# iOS 16.6 enters sleep focus 2 hours early

Tags: ios, health.app, focus

In the Health app, I have one sleep schedule, set at 12 p.m.

Wind down is set to 1h.

I would expect the OS to enter into Sleep focus at 11 a.m.

Instead, it consistently activates the Sleep focus mode at 9 a.m., or 2 hours early.

I have tried deleting all schedules and creating one from scratch, that did not help.

I am getting the chime notification about "sleep time coming soon", so I don't activate it by mistake.

I have not changed timezones since I've reset the sleep schedule.